What's the best virtual device to design lightweight projects in Android Studio?
I'm learning Android Studio and it takes my laptop over a minute to run a program where I literally have one button and one textview on the activity_main.xml. I'm assuming, a lot of that has to do with the emulator. Any advice for what to choose when creating a new emulator that really just executes the code and doesn't emulate complex features, unnecessary for a simple project? Thanks.

stackoverflow doen't like software suggestion questions at all, it considers them too broad and opinion-based, just fyi

I didn't mean for it to be a software question. I'm in Android studio and device manager allows me to design my own. I'm looking for settings advice or whatever to pair everything down so the whole thing uses less memory. Is there a phone option in there that's good for just testing and doesn't have google maps on it as well for example.

yes, that's another story, I was just not educated enough in terms of AS to recognise it
